# Use getUserMedia with ionic get only black screen

Tags: ionic-framework, getusermedia

Im testing some media features with ionic and im stuck while trying to set the camera output into a video tag using getUserMedia using this code:

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                     navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                     navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
   navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: false, video: { width: 500, height: 500 } },
      function(stream) {
         console.log("Im streaming!!", stream);
         var video = document.querySelector('video');
         console.log("video element", video);
         video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
         video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
            console.log("stream start");
            video.play();
         };
      },
      function(err) {
         console.log("The following error occurred: " + err.name);
      }
   );
} else {
   console.log("getUserMedia not supported");
}
```

this is the html:

```
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
        <video  id="video" autoplay="autoplay" width="500" height="500"></video>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
```

i can actually get only a black screen. Is my approach right or im missing something?

Comment: did you try to remove `video.onloadedmetadata` and call `video.play()` directly?

Comment: i can see "stream start" in the console so i think video.play() is called correctly

Comment: can you check if you have the correct permissions in the android manifest file `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`

Comment: yes i ve them both

Comment: did reproduced the problem on a cordova app, and managed to overcome the problem by setting the camera to rear. it was by default to front

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The final solution to this problem is that getUserMedia require a runtime permission check to work. To achieve that i used [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-opentok-android-permissions) plugin. Then this worked like a charm:

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestRuntimePermission(function(status){
    if(cordova.plugins.diagnostic.runtimePermissionStatus.GRANTED){
      navigator.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: false}, function(localMediaStream) {
        var video = document.querySelector('video');
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);

        video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
          console.log('Stream is on!!', e);
        };
      }, errorCallback);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 4):

I managed to reproduce the problem and solved it by using the `constraints` options. Using `constraints` you can set the `sourceId` that allows you to select between front or rear camera. Im sure that your device has no front camera and i guess this is why you are getting the black screen.

First we create our constraint options:

```
var constraints = {};

MediaStreamTrack.getSources (function(sources) {
    sources.forEach(function(info) {
        if (info.facing == "environment") {
            constraints = {
              video: {
                optional: [{sourceId: info.id}]
              }
            };
        }
    })
})
```

Then we call the `navigator.getUserMedia`:

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
   navigator.getUserMedia(constraints,
      function(stream) {
         console.log("Im streaming!!", stream);
         var video = document.querySelector('video');
         console.log("video element", video);
         video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
         video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
            console.log("stream start");
            video.play();
         };
      },
      function(err) {
         console.log("The following error occurred: " + err.name);
      }
   );
} else {
   console.log("getUserMedia not supported");
}
```

**Warning**: `MediaStreamTrack.getSources` returns a promise so that means that if you try to run your `navigator.getUserMedia` code at once, it will fail. You will have to wrap it in a function and run it as a callback.

More info about camera and audio source selection can be found here: 
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/media-devices

also a nice example here:
https://simpl.info/getusermedia/sources/

Comment: Thanks, I will try your solution!!

Comment: @Vanojx1 yes sure mate tell me when u do

Comment: my device ve front camera, i ve tested your solution using ionic and it wont work ( still black screen )... but it works ( only with front camera ) using browser on simpl.info website. I think is something related to ionic

Comment: @Vanojx1 are you getting console errors? I am sure that the `constraints` options will solve your problem. Have a read on the articles i posted as well, they explain in details how things work

Comment: im having this in console "file:///android_asset/www/null" as a GET error